# Is that true that somebody was punished by the Catholic Church for believing that a fly had six feet?

Tags: catholic-church, science

It is often claimed that Catholic Church punished scientists who relied on the experiment rather than just believing certain approved thinkers.

As an example, it is often put forward that in one of the Aristotle's works he claims that a fly has 8 feet, and allegedly the Church persecuted anybody who claimed otherwise for heresy or for sorcery.

Does it have any historical basis?

Comment: Do you have a source for the allegation? It could help narrow the search down.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a better fit for Skeptics SE. (But it needs to meet certain documentation requirements for that site.

Answer (score 6):

Most probably just a myth. See [here](http://scienceblogs.com/evolvingthoughts/2008/09/16/aristotle-on-the-mayfly/) for a detailed analysis of Aristotle's actual writings on the the issue, and the ensuing debunking of the myth.